# I am getting Gradle DSL method not found error?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am developing news app and I am getting following errors.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()'
Possible causes: The project 'app' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.2.0 and sync project The project 'app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin.
```

I have followed all possible solution from stack overflow but it did not solve my issue.

below my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'key0'
                keyPassword 'Adilnoz1992'
                storeFile file('yodgor.jks')
                storePassword 'Aziyoda1990'
            }
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.edgar.komilov.news"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        flavorDimensions "default"
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below my root `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra curly brace `}` which is above `compileSdkVersion 28` and add it above `dependencies` block as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
            config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'Adilnoz1992'
            storeFile file('yodgor.jks')
            storePassword 'Aziyoda1990'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.edgar.komilov.news"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        flavorDimensions "default"
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thansk Bek for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' // should have the same version as appcompat
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

And the google services in your root `build.gradle` to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Also, add `compileSdkVersion 28` inside `android` block:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    ..
```

Then try.

Comment: I am getting following error Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [28] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (8 s 570 ms)

11:24 AM Gradle sync started

11:24 AM Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [28] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2 s 19 ms)

Comment: Which version of Android Studio you are using? It seems like you need to update your Android Studio to v3.2 since: `project 'app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method` if you already didn't

Comment: what do you think solution to this problem do you think

Comment: Updating Android Studio to v 3.2 (if you already didn't) then following my answer and rebuild-project. Or, see this : `Open Gradle wrapper file The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin` go to your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and replace the link with this: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` - The easiest solution will be updating whole gradle plugin - wrapper to latest stable version.

Comment: Mohsen I have done as you told error still appearing

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip I have added that already

Comment: You didn't mention about your Android Studio version? May I know which version you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.2 android version

Comment: @Mohsin what do you think problem is

Comment: Check the other Answer. Just like I said, add compilesdkversion inside `android` block and there seems to be an extra `}` which you need to give it a try removing it.